# Assembly program gives me unwanted character as an output ??asm

Tags: assembly

My program is supposed to ask the user to enter a text line, then it tells how many digits is there, if there's no digit, it says"no digit", otherwise it  gives the number of digits in the text. The problem is that when it prints the number of digits, it prints a smiley face from the ASCII instead

here's my code

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H

.DATA
MSG1  DB  "Enter a line of text : $"
MSG2  DB  0DH,0AH,"Number of digits : $"
MSG3  DB  0DH,0AH,"No digits !$"
```

..........

Comment: What Do You expect? You need to convert correctly to the corresponding hex code.

Comment: @icbytes: You mean ASCII character.

Comment: if i enter "er45" it's supposed to tell me " **The number of digits: 2** " instead of " **The number of digits: ☻** " That's the problem.

Comment: Surely i meant the hexadecimal repreaentation of the corresponding ascii code.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the value 0 isn't the same thing as the character 0 (`'0'`), the value 1 isn't the same thing as the character 1, and so on.

You'll have to change the printing code to:

```
MOV AH, 2               
MOV DL, COUNT
ADD DL,'0'   ; convert from 0..9 to '0'..'9'       
INT 21H
```

Note that this will only work if `COUNT` is <= 9. For larger values it gets more complicated, as you'll have to implement a loop that repeatedly divides by 10 and places the remainder + '0' in a buffer that you then can print.